# Stop two way data binding on angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass information to a directive like this:

```
<ui-message data="{{app}}"></ui-message>
```

**Where in my controller I have the following:**

```
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.app = "Hello World!"
})
```

**And my directive:**

```
app.directive("uiMessage", function() {
  return {
    template: "<h1>{{message}}</h1>",
    scope: {
      message: "@data"
    }
  }
})
```

That works fine, except that if `app` is bound to a model, it'll update the content inside the directive:

```
<input ng-model="app"> //typing here changes the content inside ui-message
<ui-message data="{{app}}"></ui-message>
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why are you binding `ng-model` to `app` if you don't want to update `app`? Set literally any other model.

Comment: This is just an example. I don't need the solution to a real-world case, just for curiosity (and in case I need to use it sometime)

Comment: sorry that people who don't know one-way and one-time databinding downvoted you. Your question is very valid and limiting the number of watchers is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [one time binding expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) with `::`

```js
function uiMessage() {
  return {
    template: "<h1>{{::msg}}</h1>",
    scope: {
      msg: "="
    }
  }
}
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.message = "one way";
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', myController)
    .directive('uiMessage', uiMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <ui-message msg="message"></ui-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it's really a one time thing you're after and you're not going to need the variable, you can use ng-transclude instead of creating a scope:

```js
function uiMessage() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: "<h1 ng-transclude></h1>"
  }
}
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.message = "one way";
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', myController)
    .directive('uiMessage', uiMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <ui-message>{{::message}}</ui-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One-way binding with "@" works in the opposite direction from what you're thinking - it prevents changes in the directive from being replicated back to the parent scope, not changes in the parent scope from affecting the directive.  What you probably want to do is use angular.copy to copy your data, then pass that copy to your directive.

```
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.app = "Hello World!"
  $scope.appCopy = angular.copy($scope.app);
})
```

At that point there's no need for one-way data binding in your template:

```
<ui-message data="appCopy"></ui-message>
```

Or your directive

```
app.directive("uiMessage", function() {
  return {
    template: "<h1>{{message}}</h1>",
    scope: {
      message: "=data"
    }
  }
})
```